# ¿Qué es mejor? Un archivo con rutas o un controlador de rutas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rutas, router

Tengo un dilema con este problema.

Entre a trabajar en una empresa donde tienen un sistema con laravel. Hasta ahí todo bien. Mis conflictos empiezan en no saber que es mejor. Si utilizar su sistema que hicieron para el ruteo, o si usar el sistema de ruteo de laravel.

El ruteo de ellos funciona de la siguiente manera.

crean una ruta dinámica:

```
Route::get('sec/{parametro}/mod/{parametro}/{accion}', 'algoController@index');
```

En el método al que hace referencia manda a llamar el controlador que termina construyendo con los parámetros de la ruta. En otras palabras crea un controlador que controla las rutas.

En mi caso yo hice un comando nuevo para Artisan que llame make:createmodule el cual lleva acabo la tarea de crear una nueva estructura para el modulo, de igual manera este comando agrega al archivo web.php las rutas para manejar el controlador creado. Esto en código se ve asi:

```
Route::get('sec/nombre/mod/nombre/index', 'nombreController@index');

Route::post('sec/nombre/mod/nombre/create', 'nombreController@create');
```

etc.

Mi duda es cual de las dos opciones es mejor. Por un lado con mi método es más directo y no carga tantos archivos.

Pero por otro lado el archivo web.php por cada modulo nuevo crecerá haciéndolo menos sostenible.

¿ustedes que recomiendan? ¿tienen alguna otra idea de como manejar esto?

Como dato extra trabajos con alrededor de 100 módulos diferentes.

Comment: Pero no hacen ambos metodos lo mismo? en ambas formas una ruta llama a la accion de un controlador por cada una o no?

Comment: Tu método personalizado permite la gestión de los parámetros cuando se llama al método del controlador? Personalmente te recomiendo que sigas usando el de Laravel. Ya está hecho, está probado, y si viene otra persona no tiene que aprender otro método de enrutado.

Comment: Si ambos métodos hacen lo mismo pero no se cual es mas eficiente y mantenible.

Comment: El comando que hice para laravel si permite personalizar varios parámetros, es como usar el comando make:controller.